# How much memory cost call of recursive function PHP

Tags: php, memory-management, recursion

I have recursive function:

```
function find($index, &$itemsCounts, &$amountsSums, $deep)
```

and in this function I call it again:

```
find($index, &$itemsCounts, &$amountsSums, $deep+1)
```

the max deep was 182 and peak of allocated memory was 751MB... I do not understand what takes so much memory in that recursive call....

Can somebody explain it? Does anybody know how much memory takes storing one that call on stack?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
the function looks like:

```
private function findChod($index, &$itemsCounts, &$amountsSums, $deep){
    if($amountsSums['a'] > $this->upperLimit) return;
      $check_string = "";

      if($deep > $this->maxDeep) $this->maxDeep = $deep;

    foreach ($this->x[$index]['a'] as $key => $item) {
      $check_string = $check_string." ".$itemsCounts[$key];
    }

    if(isset($this->memo[$check_string]))
      return;

    $this->memo[$check_string] = 1;

     $a = "asda;"
     $b = "asda;"
     $c = "asda;"
     $d = "asda;"
     $e = "asda;"
     $f = "asda;"

    if() return;

    if(){
      if(){
        $this->compareWithBest($amountsSums, $itemsCounts, abs($fatsDifference)+abs($protsDifference)+abs($carbsDifference));
      }
    }

    unset($a);
    unset($b);
    unset($c);

    unset($d);
    unset($e);
    unset($f);

    foreach ($this->x[$index]['items'] as $key => $item) {
      $amountsSums['a'] +=  $item['a'] * $item['unit'];
      $amountsSums['b'] +=  $item['b'] * $item['unit'] ;
      $amountsSums['c'] +=  $item['c'] * $item['unit'];
      $amountsSums['d'] +=  $item['d'] * $item['unit'];
      $itemsCounts[$key]++;

      $this->find($index, $itemsCounts, $amountsSums, $deep+1);

      $amountsSums['a'] -=  $item['a'] * $item['unit'];
      $amountsSums['b'] -=  $item['b'] * $item['unit'];
      $amountsSums['c'] -=  $item['c'] * $item['unit'];
      $amountsSums['d'] -=  $item['d'] * $item['unit'];
      $itemsCounts[$key]--;
    }
  }
```

where memo has at peak 1 900 000 items...
and I`m using php 5.5.3

**EDIT2:**
I discovered that variable memo takes cca 307MB

**EDIT3:**
I rewrite my algorithm so I did not need memory at all...

Comment: Can you show the contents of `find($args,...)` function. By the way what is your PHP version.

Comment: This depends greatly on what the `find` function is *doing* each time it's called.

Comment: Unless you are using an old PHP4 call time pass by reference is deprecated. You recurse with `find($index, $itemsCounts, $amountsSums, $deep+1)`. This doesn't explain your memory usage though so you should edit the question and add the whole definition of `find`.

Comment: Yes it is but I am not using call time pass by reference... I still do not understand what takes so much memory here...

Comment: Does `unset($check_string)` (before the recursive call) help? `$itemsCounts` might also become big. Hmm, You have to do debug and see the memory usage. I'm not sure if this is possible at all with PHP. xdebug might help.

Comment: @Sylwester using references is in this case a good idea. Otherwise those arrays would be copied for each call on the stack. This would indeed be a nice candidate for his OOM.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch Really, would they be copied even if the function prototype said it was referenced? I'd guess the real difference then would be the warnings.

Comment: @Sylwester In this case I don't think so (and simply don't know). I just wanted to emphasize that those arrays should be indeed references to minimize the memory foot print.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch See [PHP pass by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). see the note: *There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function definitions* And you'll get a fatal error from 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's arrays are far away from classical arrays. It's a data structure which implements a linked list and a hash table. There's a lot of overhead which reflects obviously in memory consumption. I don't know no implementation detail about them, but the fact that it eats 300MB for only 1900000 * (10 byte indexes + 4 byte values) implies that you just cannot have large arrays in PHP.

I just recently learned that PHP offers indeed access to a classical array which consumes far less memory. PHP calls it [`SplFixedArray`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php). But this won't help you, as you in deed need the functionality of a hash map.

Comment: are you sure that this is the case... my loop is of length 5 but if I am right then it calls function find sychnronous... it means that it will wait for return of that function... so on stack can be actually just these 182 function calls

Comment: Not sure, just guessing. Use a debugger to see what's going on. But I think it's very likely that your stack get filled with those calls. Each find() is calling 5 times find() (which is calling 5 times find(), …). This explodes quickly.

Comment: I edited my answer to adapt the point that this high depth might not be a problem with the stack but more likely with the heap.

Comment: I would correct you: which can not explode on the way to 2^182 because if you look at that code itemCounts has just 4 indexes and memo has 1 900 000 indexes and on each one of them is number 1...

Comment: Obvisously `$memo` exploded. The value `1` should in a perfect world need something between 2 and 4 bytes. But your indexes (`$check_string`) will eat a lot of memory.

Comment: check_string has max length 10 char

Comment: PHP's arrays are far away from classical arrays. It's a data structure which implements a linked list and a hash table. There's a lot of overhead which reflects obviously in memory consumption. I don't know no implementation detail about them, but the fact that it eats 300MB for only 1900000 * (10 byte indexes + 4 byte values) implies that you just cannot have large arrays in PHP.

Comment: Hi there, It looks like it is how you says... If you will change your answer I will accept it... And btw. solution for me was rewriting algorithm so it does not consume almost any memory (kB)